# Postfix errors when relaying from external hosts

Tags: postfix

I am trying to setup Postfix to relay email from an external hosts. One of the hosts in the "mynetworks" is working great. One of them is not. Both hosts are using the same code, but I can't understand the debug I am looking at. Can anyone spot the error?

```
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  mail
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  ipv4
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: name_mask: ipv4
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  smtp1.BLAH.net
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  BLAH.net
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  Postfix
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: expand ${multi_instance_name:postfix}${multi_instance_name?$multi_instance_name} -> postfix
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  postfix
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  postdrop
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: expand $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain -> smtp1.BLAH.net, localhost.BLAH.net, localhost, BLAH.net
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: expand $mydomain -> BLAH.net
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  /usr/libexec/postfix
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  /var/lib/postfix
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  /usr/sbin
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  /var/spool/postfix
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  pid
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  all
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  double-bounce
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  nobody
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  hash:/etc/aliases
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  20100319
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  2.6.6
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  hash
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  deferred, defer
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: expand $mydestination -> smtp1.BLAH.net, localhost.BLAH.net, localhost, BLAH.net
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: expand $relay_domains -> smtp1.BLAH.net, localhost.BLAH.net, localhost, BLAH.net
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  TZ MAIL_CONFIG LANG
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  MAIL_CONFIG MAIL_DEBUG MAIL_LOGTAG TZ XAUTHORITY DISPLAY LANG=C
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  subnet
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  127.0.0.1
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  +=
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  -=+
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  debug_peer_list,fast_flush_domains,mynetworks,permit_mx_backup_networks,qmqpd_authorized_clients,relay_domains,smtpd_access_maps
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  bounce
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  cleanup
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  defer
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  pickup
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  qmgr
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  rewrite
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  showq
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  error
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  flush
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  verify
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  trace
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  proxymap
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  proxywrite
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  3
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  31457280
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  100s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  100s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  100s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  100s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  3600s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  3600s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  5s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  5s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  1000s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  1000s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  10s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  10s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  1s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  1s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  1s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  1s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  500s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  500s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  18000s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  18000s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  1s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  1s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  192.235.X.X, 192.235.X.X, 10.254.254.0/24, 127.0.0.0/8
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: inet_addr_local: configured 2 IPv4 addresses
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  10
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: expand ${stress?1}${stress:20} -> 20
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: expand ${stress?1}${stress:100} -> 100
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: expand ${stress?1}${stress:3} -> 3
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  550
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: expand $myhostname ESMTP -> smtp1.BLAH.net ESMTP
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  resource, software, bounce, 2bounce, delay, policy, protocol
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  postmaster
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: expand $virtual_maps ->
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  hash:/etc/aliases
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: expand proxy:unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps -> proxy:unix:passwd.byname hash:/etc/aliases
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  noanonymous
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  smtpd
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  CONNECT GET POST
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  <>
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: expand $double_bounce_sender -> double-bounce
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: expand $authorized_verp_clients ->
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: expand $myhostname -> smtp1.BLAH.net
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: expand ${smtpd_client_connection_limit_exceptions:$mynetworks} -> 192.235.X.X, 192.235.X.X, 10.254.254.0/24, 127.0.0.0/8
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  permit_inet_interfaces
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: expand $smtpd_sasl_security_options -> noanonymous
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: expand $smtpd_tls_cert_file ->
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: expand $smtpd_tls_dcert_file ->
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: expand $smtpd_tls_eccert_file ->
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  export
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  medium
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  SSLv3, TLSv1
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  none
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  md5
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  cyrus
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  j {daemon_name} v
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  {tls_version} {cipher} {cipher_bits} {cert_subject} {cert_issuer}
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  i {auth_type} {auth_authen} {auth_author} {mail_addr} {mail_host} {mail_mailer}
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  i {rcpt_addr} {rcpt_host} {rcpt_mailer}
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  i
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  i
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  i
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  6
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  tempfail
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: expand $myhostname -> smtp1.BLAH.net
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: expand $mail_name $mail_version -> Postfix 2.6.6
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  defer_if_permit
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: expand $reject_tempfail_action -> defer_if_permit
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: expand $reject_tempfail_action -> defer_if_permit
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: expand $reject_tempfail_action -> defer_if_permit
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: expand $reject_tempfail_action -> defer_if_permit
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: expand ${stress?10}${stress:300}s -> 300s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: expand ${stress?10}${stress:300}s -> 300s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  1s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  1s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  100s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  100s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  3s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  3s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  100s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  100s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  300s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  300s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  1000s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  1000s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  300s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  300s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  3600s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  3600s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  30s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  30s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  30s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  30s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  300s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: dict_eval: const  300s
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: process generation: 21 (21)
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: match_string: mynetworks ~? debug_peer_list
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: match_string: mynetworks ~? fast_flush_domains
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: match_string: mynetworks ~? mynetworks
May 16 19:49:59 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: match_string: relay_domains ~? debug_peer_list
May 16 19:51:40 smtp1 postfix/smtpd[30138]: idle timeout -- exiting
```

Comment: I don't think this debug log is useful or necessary for solving your problem. Most of the configuration problems are solved by looking at the configuration. I think you have `192.235.X.X, 192.235.X.X, 10.254.254.0/24, 127.0.0.0/8` in your `mynetworks`, which would be fine (if the `X`s are numbers). Is the client really connecting directly from those IPs?

Comment: Yes, I only have those two IPs open in my firewall. Do you think its actually a different IP in the SMTP client versus where it comes from over the internet maybe?

Comment: I solved it. Turns out the second server was trying to use SSL so thats why the logs didn't show much. Turning off SSL fixed it.